# Open every window only once

Tags: java, javafx

I have a chart. A double click on a table row opens a window in which I can edit the information of the row. Double-clicking on another line opens the corresponding window. Everything works as it should, except that each window should open only once. If it is already open, the window should return to the foreground. Unfortunately I can't see what's wrong here and would be grateful for a hint

```
private void loadTable() {

    // I omitted the part where the table is populated.

    mytable.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            if (event.isPrimaryButtonDown() && event.getClickCount() == 2) {

                TableItem table_item = table_view.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

                try {

                    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
                    fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/application/Popup.fxml"));

                    Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
                    Stage stage = new Stage();   
                    stage.setScene(scene);
                    MyController controller = fxmlLoader.<MyController>getController();
                    boolean result = controller.init(stage, table_item);              

                    if (stage.isShowing()) {
                        stage.toFront();
                        System.out.println("Show this popup.");
                    } else {                        
                        if (result) {                                   
                            stage.show();
                            System.out.println("Open this popup.");
                        }
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You are creating a new `Stage` every time the mouse handler executes. You say you only want to create it the first time the user double clicks on a particular row in the table. How do you think you can manage that?

Comment: The only thing I would suggest is that you save the numbers of the rows you had opened a Window for. Each time you get a click, you compare the number with the list of numbers of the opened windows, if you don't find it you create, else you bring it to the foreground (I don't know how to do that).

Comment: You could do this by creating a stage field in your class the first thing you would need to do in you event handler is check for null if null create necessary stuff if not null check if showing if so pull to front else show stage

Comment: You can create a boolean variable with scope of the whole class. Use it to keep up with if a popup is already open. If it is, close the old window before opening the new one. Create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and I will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
```

after

```
Stage stage = new Stage();
```

This will make the `Parent` stage unclickable until this stage is closed.